# Angular Material Settings for Card Location

Tags: angular, angular-material

We will be putting cards on a page and wanted to save the users preferred location if they move or arrange the cards in a different order. Clearly using the Component Dev Kit drag and drop to do the rearranging of the order.

We would like to save these so when they come back to the page we can have the cards be in the order the next time (new session, or just later that session).

But not seeing any examples for where to even start, so that cards can be arranged in any order other than a hard coded order.

Comment: can you please elaborate the question

Comment: @Aravind edited the question, hope that helps.